# Button not showing in LinearLayout

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am using LinearLayout to display a simple title, body, and Save and Cancel buttons. But I can't see the Save button. What is missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:layout_margin="12dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_title"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_body"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec est consequat arcu laoreet consequat non eget quam. Mauris ullamcorper odio id erat pharetra, sed auctor libero tempor. Sed sit amet justo facilisis nisl pharetra mollis. Donec vel felis eget dolor tristique consectetur at nec tortor. Donec eu finibus leo. Fusce non erat semper turpis tincidunt volutpat sit amet sit amet elit."
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The layout looks OK. When you say you can't see the "save" button, what do you mean exactly. Can you post what you are seeing?

Comment: @Cheticamp The Save button doesn't appear on the android device, I don't know if it overlapped or why it simply does not display "Save" button., I only see title, Edittext and Cancel button at the bottom.

Comment: Is there vertical space showing for the Save button? I mean, is the text for the button just not showing? Maybe it has the same color as the background?

Comment: No, I'm using a template with purple background for both save and cancel buttons.

Comment: It looks good to me as I mentioned above. I would take a look at the layout in the Layout Inspector to try to figure out what's going on. I take it that it looks OK in the design studio just not on the device/emulator.

Comment: @Cheticamp It appears that the xml is not updating change made. I already tried invalidate cache and restart, what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was another fragment_second.xml as v26 in layout folder, after deleting this, it worked like a charm!